# Entity framework fluent mapping many-to-may

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, many-to-many, fluent

I'm having a problem when I try to map this model:

```
public class Discipline
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DisciplineRequirement> Requirements {get;set;}
}

public class DisciplineRequirement
{
    public int DisciplineId {get;set;}
    public int RequiredDiscipline {get;set;}
    public virtual Discipline Discipline {get;set;}
    public virtual Discipline RequiredDiscipline {get;set;}
}
```

Mapping code:

```
public class DisciplineMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Discipline>
{
    public DisciplineMap()
    {
        ToTable("Discipline");

        HasKey(p => p.Id);

        HasMany(p => p.Requirements)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Discipline)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.DisciplineId);

        HasMany(p => p.Requirements)
            .WithRequired(p => p.RequiredDiscipline)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RequiredDisciplineId);
    }
}

public class DisciplineRequirementMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DisciplineRequeriment>
{
    public DisciplineRequirementMap()
    {
        ToTable("DisciplineRequirement");

        HasKey(p => new
        {
            p.DisciplineId,
            p.RequiredDisciplineId
        });

        HasRequired(p => p.Discipline)
            .WithMany(p => p.Requirements)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.DisciplineId);

        HasRequired(p => p.RequiredDiscipline)
            .WithMany(p => p.Requirements)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RequiredDisciplineId);

    }
}
```

I've got this error:

*One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Requirements: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'Requirements' is not valid. Type 'DisciplineRequeriment' of FromRole 'Discipline_Requirements_Target' in AssociationType 'Discipline_Requirements' must exactly match with the type 'Discipline' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.*

Can anyone give me a light here?

Comment: It seems like you might have a stray typo somewhere: "Type `'DisciplineRequeriment'` of FromRole ". It seems to be a valid class you have defined elsewhere.

Comment: You state you want a many-to-many but your datamodel suggests a one-to-many between Discipline and DisciplineRequirement because of that DisciplineId field in the latter table. A many-to-many model shouldn't have that.

Comment: Or is DisciplineRequirement actually the join table? If so you shouldn't be trying to model it at all. EF wants to handle many to many relationships behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho, you **must** have two navigation properties (or at least if just one you can't configure it with two FKs)

```
public class Discipline
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DisciplineRequirement> Requirements {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DisciplineRequirement> RequiredBy {get;set;}
}

public class DisciplineRequirement
{
    public int DisciplineId {get;set;}
    public int RequiredDisciplineId {get;set;}
    public virtual Discipline Discipline {get;set;}
    public virtual Discipline RequiredDiscipline {get;set;}
}
```

with

```
public class DisciplineMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Discipline>
{
    public DisciplineMap()
    {
        ToTable("Discipline");

        HasKey(p => p.Id);
    }
}

public class DisciplineRequirementMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DisciplineRequeriment>
{
    public DisciplineRequirementMap()
    {
        ToTable("DisciplineRequirement");

        HasKey(p => new
        {
            p.DisciplineId,
            p.RequiredDisciplineId
        });

        HasRequired(p => p.Discipline)
            .WithMany(p => p.RequiredBy)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.DisciplineId);

        HasRequired(p => p.RequiredDiscipline)
            .WithMany(p => p.Requirements)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RequiredDisciplineId);

    }
}
```

should be enough.

Comment: Thank you... is exactly that light that I was looking for!